# Why is Opencv Findcontour behaving differently in Emgu c#?

Tags: c#, emgucv

Hi in opencv c+ method `Findcontours` return the array hierarchy and to get the boundaries of the hole I can get the hierarchy .
how can i get these boundaries in emgu cv please any help?
how can i find holes in emgu cv?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Contour hierarchy in Emgucv by using this following code.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> Img_Result_Bgr = Img_Source_Bgr.Copy();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Org_Gray = Img_Source_Bgr.Convert<Gray, byte>();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_CannyEdge_Gray = new Image<Gray, byte>(Img_Source_Bgr.Width,Img_Source_Bgr.Height);

Img_CannyEdge_Gray = Img_Org_Gray.Canny(10, 50);
Img_Org_Gray.Dispose();

Random Rnd = new Random();

#region Finding Contours
using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage()) //allocate storage for contour approximation
    for (Contour<Point> contours = Img_CannyEdge_Gray.FindContours(); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
    {
        Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage);//if you want to Approximate the contours into a polygon play with this function().

        if (contours.Area > 100) //only consider contours with area greater than 100
        {
            Img_Result_Bgr.Draw(contours, new Bgr(Rnd.Next(255),Rnd.Next(255),Rnd.Next(255)), 2);
        }
    }
#endregion
Img_CannyEdge_Gray.Dispose();

imageBox1.Image = Img_Result_Bgr;
```

For further Reference use this [Online Tutor!](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial)
Here is the output of this code.
http://s18.postimg.org/511xwpm15/Forum_Contour.jpg

Comment: thanks 
but i want to find holes in the image can this code help me?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZ6w.png
this the image i want to find the inner hole??

Comment: Use threshold to Binarise the image & play with different Parameters of findContour()http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/028cb9c4-eb4b-aa5d-242e-273ac7e227e2.htm Function to find the hole.