# EmguCV - How to find List<Contour<Point>> coordinates?

Tags: list, point, emgucv, contour, area

I just want to know how to extract some element in a list of contours points.

Basically, I have this:

```
List<Contour<Point>> contoursList = new List<Contour<Point>>;
contourList.Add(contours); //that contours variable is a Contour<Point> that i receive in a .FindContour method.
```

then I need to select/extract/whatever one specific element of this list and find its coordinate. So how can I do this?

And please, any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402133/why-is-opencv-findcontour-behaving-differently-in-emgu-c/24445282#24445282)?

Use Property Filters like Area, Contour Length & Center of Each contours to Filter your desired Contours Co-Ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do:

1. First, create a Contour variable
2. as you enumerate the contour when you execute FindCountour() method, push the current contour to the variable you declared in 1.
3. Select specific element based on your criteria

See the sample code below:

```
                //variable to hold the contour
                Contour<Point> contours = null;

                for (var contour = binaryImage.FindContours(CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
                RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_CCOMP, mem);
                contour != null;
                contour = contour.HNext)
                {
                    if (contours == null)
                    {
                        //this is to ensure contours is not null
                        contours = contour;
                    }

                    //push/add the sequence of points to contours
                    contours.PushMulti(contour.ToArray(), BACK_OR_FRONT.BACK);
                }

                //do what you want with it
                var ch = contours.GetConvexHull(ORIENTATION.CV_CLOCKWISE, mem);

                //for example, convert these points to type PointF
                PointF[] pointfs = Array.ConvertAll(contours.ToArray(), input => new PointF(input.X, input.Y));

                //or detect the bounding rectangle
                var roi = PointCollection.BoundingRectangle(pointfs);
```