# FindContour: Measure distance between contours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour, edge-detection

I would be very thankful to know further on post: [Finding Minimum Distance between Contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619645/finding-minimum-distance-between-contours/31432748#31432748)

I am using FindContours and as required getting multiple contours. 
The problem is that I want to find min distance between each adjacent pair,
e.g. between yellow contour and dark green, between dark green and cyan, between cyan and purple.

I understood the general method from above post.
But can anyone please tell me how can i select them one after another(automaticaly)?

[image]

```
void thresh_function(int, void*)
{

        Mat canny_output;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;


      /// Detect edges using canny
        Canny( roiImg, canny_output, threshold_value, threshold_value*2, 3 );
      /// Find contours
        findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

      /// Draw contours
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
        for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
         {
           Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
           drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );//Scalar(255,255,255)
         }

        erode(drawing,drawing,erodeElement2);
        erode(drawing,drawing,erodeElement1);
        dilate(drawing,drawing,dilateElement);

      /// Show in a window
     //namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     resize(drawing, enlargeD0, Size(), 2, 2, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
     done = 1;
     imshow("Contours", enlargeD0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<vector<Point> > all_contours;
... 
findContours(... all_contours ... CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE ...);
...

// Remove small contours
int minSize = 20;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
contours.reserve(all_contours.size());
for(int i=0; i<all_contours.size(); ++i)
{
    if(all_contours[i].size() > minSize) 
    {
         contours.push_back(all_contours[i]);
    }
}  

Mat1f dist(contours.size(), contours.size(), 0.f);
for(int i=0; i<contours.size()-1; ++i)
{
    const vector<Point>& firstContour = contours[i];
    for(int j=i+1; j<contours.size(); ++j)
    {
        const vector<Point>& secondContour = contours[j];
        float d = compute_pairwise_distance(firstContour, secondContour); // You should implement this
        dist(i,j) = d;
        dist(j,i) = d;  // distance from first to second is equal
                        // to distance from second to first 
    }
}

// Now dist contains the pairwise distances between i-th and j-th contours
```

Comment: is Mat1f available in OpenCV 2.4.9?

Comment: Yes, is just a typedef of `Mat_<float>`. You can use generic `Mat` with type `CV_32FC1` if you prefer, but then you need to access it with `distances.at<float>(...)`

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I have still small doubt, notice there is a contour (skyblue colored after the yellow one) in the image that i couldn't get rid of during the filtering stage. :( I do not want distance of that contour meddling in it.

Comment: @Mandar the simplest thing to do is to remove small contours, according to their size. You may want to use `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` to get all pixels in the contour, so the size of the contour is in fact the number of pixels.  See updated answer.

Comment: foolish of me to ask, but still, why do you keep using ++i ?

Comment: @Mandar a small typo in nested for loop. You should increment j, not i. Edited.

Comment: @Mandar if you find this answer useful, please accept and/or upvote. If your issue as stated in your question is not resolved, please let me know so to try to find a solution.

Comment: hi Miki, I left a question here, maybe you can help, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504073/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-concentric-contours-for-different-angles  wondering if there is more performance /speedier way to conduct this, without physically drawing lines to intersect, want to extend to other types of images https://ibb.co/6XBJn7q