# JS - Efficient way to calculate shortest point between two boundaries

Tags: javascript

Basically what I am looking for is very similar to the following (although I am writing this in javascript):

[Finding Minimum Distance between Contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619645/finding-minimum-distance-between-contours)

I have an image where I have already calculated outlines for multiple shapes and I want to connect the shapes if some point from object 1 and another point from object 2 share a minimum distance less than `d`.

The problem is that the accepted answer in that question seems to suggest looping through all points in object 2 for each point in object 1 which appears super inefficient to me. In my case scenario I will have multiple objects with large paths so that approach would not be feasible,

Is there some smarter method to approach this problem calculating the shortest point between two boundaries?

Comment: you could split all the points from objects into areas like: top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left for example, areas shoud encroach to adjacent areas over "minimum distance". Then if point from object 1 is in area 3 search throught all point from object 2 - area 3. There is ideal ratio of areas depend on space and minimum distance.

Comment: @MarekJanoud Thanks for that suggestion. I was actually thinking of the exact same thing funnily enough - but although that would probably work well for the most case scenarios - it is possible that the shapes could all be intertwined (worst case scenario) resulting in all points being compared to all points (super slow). If possible I'm looking for some solution that will work in all case scenerios

Comment: @WorstForum I'm not sure if I totally understand what you're talking about but I have a feeling that wouldn't work because the shapes could be convex, wrap around each other (basically the only requirement is that they aren't connected) other than that they could be in any weird configuration. So there might not necessarily be a "closest side" if you know what I mean. Tell me if you think I'm misunderstanding your idea.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem