# Distance between points in contours opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to develop a solution to segment corneal tomographies, and check for the distance between the cornea and a contact lens. For such, i thresholded the image and extracted the biggest 3 contours, being one of the cornea and the other 2 the interior and exterior edges of the lens.
[image: Image contours]

I need to check for the distance between the green contour and the red one all along the x axis in the image.

I tried to check for contour distance in OpenCV but did not find anything.

Comment: is the distance between two contours constant through the image somehow, or are you looking for the closest distance between them?

Comment: you might want to check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619645/finding-minimum-distance-between-contours

Comment: @aek8 i'm looking for the distance between them in various parts of the image, to check for distance variations. For example, if at the leftmost pixel the distance between them is 20% less than at the rightmost pixel, a possible irregular cornea is diagnosed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer explains how to find the radial distance between the red line and the green line. I have manually edited the image so that only the relevant parts of the image are considered.

[image: Image with non-relevant parts removed.]

The first step is to find a function that describes the curve of the lens (the red line). Scipy can find functions from data. *Scipy.interp1d()* found the function (in cyan) from the red line's contours:

[image: Curve]

Next, I could find the distance from the green line (the contours of the cornea), to the nearest point on the curve:

[image: Nearest]

Comment: Could you describe how you compute/find "to the nearest point on the curve"?

Comment: @RobertLugg I used PointPolygonTest: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d48/tutorial_point_polygon_test.html